# In what circumstances would a 1000 years on Earth be a single day

Tags: time, relativity, time-dilation, estimation

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask this question. If if isn't then please move it accordingly.

I was googling about time dilation and age of the earth and I ran into some argument by someone claiming the earth to be 7000 years old; He did mention a also in the paragraph that 1000 years on earth. I was reminded about a part in Interstellar where the protagonist spends 1 hour and it is essentially 7 years on earth.

I am not interested in the religious aspects of this , but are there circumstances where there can be this strong of time difference?  And if so, what are those circumstances? Also can this be mathematically calculated?

Would a larger planet moving around a larger sun have this effect?

Somewhat related:

[Do planets experience time dilation as they orbit the sun and if so what effect would this have on their orbit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/441964/)

[Time dilation for non-physicists](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/354549/)

Comment: There is that better ?

Comment: You can get that amount of time dilation  (1 day : 1000 years) with a *very* close orbit to a black hole that has almost the maximal spin parameter. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146105/123208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Time dilation occurs in both Special relativity, where a stationary observer and a moving observer would measure two different time intervals between the same event, and General relativity, where an observer in a strong gravitational field measures a different time interval between two events than an observer in a weaker gravitational field.

In the Special Relativistic case, all we need is an idealized (for the sake of brevity and comprehension) version of the twin paradox. Ignoring acceleration, a spaceship leaves earth with a velocity $v$, travels in a straight line, and turns around at some point and travels to earth with velocity $-v$ (same speed, opposite direction). SR tells us that the time measured by the spaceship $t'$ is related to the time measured on Earth $t$ by $$t'=t\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2},$$ where c is the speed of light. We know that $t'/t=$ (1 day)/(1000 years) = $1/365,000$. Solving for $v$, we can show that if the ship travels at 99.9999999996% the speed of light, and turns around after 12 hours, the ship will return after 1000 years have elapsed in Earth time.

In the General Relativistic case, we can imagine an observer near something very dense and massive, like a black hole or neutron star, comparing times with an observer on earth. Again idealizing the problem significantly, we can relate the stellar observer's time $t'$ to the Earth time $t$ by the equation $$t'=t\sqrt{1-2GM/rc^2},$$ where G is the gravitational constant, M is the mass of the black hole, r is the distance the stellar observer is from the center of mass of the black hole, and c is again the speed of light. This depends on both M and r, but if we choose an arbitrary M, like the mass of the nearest known black hole, V616 Monocerotis (approx. 10 times the mass of our sun), we can find out how far away we would have to be from its center of mass in order to get the specified time dilation $t'/t=1/365000$. Solving for r, we find that an observer would need to be about 20 nanometers from the event horizon of V616 Monocerotis in order to experience a time dilation of this magnitude.

Comment: Excellent answer. So 20 nanometers from the event horizon, or traveling at nearly the speed of light for 12 hours. Sounds nearly impossible .

Comment: @Qndel Yes, it's very difficult, especially if you're larger than a couple of nanometres. ;) Also, there are no stable orbits that close to a Schwarzschild black hole, see [Innermost stable circular orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Innermost_stable_circular_orbit). The situation is a bit better with a spinning black hole, as I mentioned earlier. But no matter what method you choose, the amount of energy required to achieve such speeds is insanely huge.

Answer (score 0):

You could acheive large amounts of time dilation by placing an observer in a very strong gravitational field (e.g near a black hole) or by accelerating them to near light speed relative to the Earth then decelerating them.

Answer (score -1):

A thousand years on earth would be a single (solar) day if the earthed had a sidereal rotation period of 0.999001 years.